# How to add to a List<? extend T> from a method

Tags: java, generics

Sorry coming from C# here and getting a little confused.

I have a declaration as follows:

```java
 private final HashMap<String, List<? extends Item>> inventory = new HashMap<>();
```

The `inventory` is divided into different classifications. For example `Weapons`.
So we have a `class Weapon extends Item`.

Now I have a method to add a weapon.

```java
  public void addWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
    inventory.get("weapons").add(weapon);
  }
```

This is where I hit a problem, saying the `? extends Item` expected.

Any help, or a pointer to an answer appreciated.

Comment: You can't add to a `List<? extends Item>` (without bypassing type safety) because the type it can accept is `?` (unknown). If you want a `List` that you can put any `Item` into, that's a `List<Item>`.

Comment: In C# we would add a contraint stating the T must derive from Item. How do I solve in Java? The issue is I have 3 categories, Weapons, Potions, Equipment. All extend Item

Comment: Why not use a `List<Item>`?

Comment: Because it complains when I try to add a List<Weapon>, But Weapon extends Item so I am unsure why this is not allowed

Comment: Well. If you use `List<? extends Item>`, that can be a list of any subtype of `Item`. So it could be a `List<Weapon>`. Or it could be a `List<Potion>`. Since the type is unknown, you cannot put anything in it. Alternatively, you could use `List<Item>`. Any list you use for that has to be an actual `List<Item>`, not a list of some subtype of `Item`. But the plus side is that you know the type, so you know that you can put any `Item` in it. Lastly, you could use type casting to get around the checks, because you somehow do actually know what the type is of each list.

Comment: here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your value is a List, but your adding a Weapon not a List of them, or a list of Item's, this should work:

```java
private final HashMap<String, List<Item>> inventory = new HashMap<>();

public void addWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
    inventory.get("weapons").add(weapon);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have had to do. But when I do my getter I have to cast out to Weapon.